# iPhone network node library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, nodes

I'm trying to find a library for iPhone app that can represent a network with an arbitrary number of nodes and distances between the nodes. I need to then calculate shortest path between the nodes. Does anyone know if such is available for objective-c or c++ in general that can be used in an iPhone app?

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://bit.ly/OF8727) are some implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simple enough network, you can just do a normal BFS (Breadth-First Search) or DFS (Depth-First Search) and compute all the possible paths. Then just select the fastest one.  Remember, for graphs you have to store a list of nodes that you've already visited, otherwise you'll end up going in circles forever.

Comment: I would have no problem applying Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm manually but I'm just hoping to avoid having to code a network model in Obj-C from scratch.